# Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `start_with?' for /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/:Regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Upgrading a Rails 5.2 project to Rails 6. After the upgrade, when I try to pull up the site, I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `start_with?' for /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/:Regexp
```

This is code:

```
def source_image(source)
    if source == 'blah'
        return image_tag 'blah.png', size: '18', :title => 'blah', :data => {:toggle => 'tooltip', :placement => 'right', }
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error goes from the `source_image` method? Could you please post the whole error text in the question?

Answer (score 13):

Visit `config/initializer/assets.rb`

Change

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

To This

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << ["*.svg", "*.eot", "*.woff", "*.ttf"]
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. It would be useful if somebody could explain why this change was needed.